# numpy.resize() rearanging instead of resizing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, resize

I'm trying to resize numpy array, but it seems that the resize works by first flattening the array, then getting first X*Y elem and putting them in the new shape. What I want to do instead is to cut the array at coord 3,3, not rearrange it. Similar thing happens when I try to upsize it say to 7,7 ... instead of "rearranging" I want to fill the new cols and rows with zeros and keep the data as it is.
Is there a way to do that ?

```
> a = np.zeros((5,5))
> a.flat = range(25)
> a
array(
  [[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
   [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
   [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
   [ 15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.],
   [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.]])

> a.resize((3,3),refcheck=False)
> a
array(
  [[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
   [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
   [ 6.,  7.,  8.]])
```

thank you ...

Comment: Can you please post an example of expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upsizing to 7x7 goes like this

```
upsized = np.zeros([7, 7]) 
upsized[:5, :5] = a
```

Comment: thanks that's what I needed.. You wouldn't know how to do this in place, would you ?

Comment: There is no way to do this in place if your original data `a` was created as you have. This is because `np.ndarray` data always has to be contiguous in memory, and you can't know whether there will be enough space to add the extra 24 slots to the 25 that a was already occupying to make space for 49=7x7 contiguous numbers in memory. However, if you had preallocated 49 spaces in memory, then you can do inplace editing. E.g. `b=upsized[:5, :5]` is a view on the same data (no copy!) as upsized and its content is equal to `a`, but it is no longer the same array.

Comment: I suspected it will be like this.. you are right it probably stores the array in contiguous space

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want to use numpy's slicing syntax instead of `resize`. `resize` works by first raveling the array and working with a 1D view.

```
>>> a = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
>>> a[:3,:3]
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

What you are doing here is taking a view of the numpy array. For example to update the original array by slicing:

```
>>> a[:3,:3] = 0
>>> a
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  8,  9],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

An excellent guide on numpy's slicing syntax can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Upsizing (or *padding*) only works by making a copy of the data. You start with an array of zeros and fill in appropriately

```
upsized = np.zeros([7, 7])
upsized[:5, :5] = a
```

Comment: You may want to add the upsizing part in your answer to complete it

Comment: @eickenberg You seemed to understood that part of the question, combined we may have accurately guessed what the asker wants.